# Why ngInfiniteScroll (infinite-scroll) doesn't work on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I've faced with problem that angular **infinite-scroll** doesn't work on mobile devices - tested on Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 and Samsung Galaxy 4.

> My code works correctly on PC and on **IOS** devices.

Problem reproduces only on mobile devices.

Maybe someone faced with the same issue? Can you suggest me something?

```js
$scope.loadNews = function() {
  if ($scope.position > $scope.allNews.length) return;
  if ($scope.allNews.length > $scope.news.length) {
    var partOfNews = $scope.getPartOfEntities($scope.newsPosition, $scope.scrollNewsCount, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < partOfNews.length; i++) {
      $scope.news.push(partOfNews[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div ng-hide="showSpinner">

  <div infinite-scroll='loadNews()' infinite-scroll-distance='0.5'>
    <hr>
    <news data="news"></news>

  </div>

</div>
```

```js
        handler = function() {
          var elementBottom, remaining, shouldScroll, windowBottom;
          windowBottom = $window.height() + $window.scrollTop();
          elementBottom = elem.offset().top + elem.height();
          remaining = elementBottom - windowBottom;
          shouldScroll = remaining <= $window.height() * scrollDistance;
          if (shouldScroll && scrollEnabled) {
            if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
              return scope.$eval(attrs.infiniteScroll);
            } else {
              return scope.$apply(attrs.infiniteScroll);
            }
          } else if (shouldScroll) {
            return checkWhenEnabled = true;
          }
        };

          var applied = false;
          var touchmover = function () {
              if ( ! applied) {
                  applied = true;
                  $window.on('touchend', handler);
              }
          };

          $window.on('touchmove', handler);
          scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              $window.off('touchend', handler);
              applied = false;
              return $window.off('touchmove', touchmover);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple piece of code based on scrolls

`$('#news').bind('scroll', function(){
       if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight){
        //alert(1);
        loadNews();
       }
    });`

Comment: My question is dedicated to ngInfiniteScroll. I'm not trying to find alternative approach to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i have discuvered that. If you are using

> infinite-scroll-use-document-bottom="true"

then You have to set infinite-scroll-distance to 1

> infinite-scroll-distance="1"

. it doesnt work on mobile if you set it to 0

> infinite-scroll-distance="0"